# What portion of m2t video file size is audio?

Tags: audio, file-formats

What portion of a video file is audio information? I have a large number of m2t video files where the audio is worthless to me. I'm curious if removing the audio portion from these files will notably decrease the file size. Could someone give me a ballpark estimate of how much this will decrease file size? For example, how much will a 5 GB m2t video file be reduced?

Comment: Not enough to bother re-encoding it - typically single figure %

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that with [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/de/MediaInfo). It will tell you exactly how much space each stream (in your case, the video and the audio stream) of a video takes up and give both the absolute and the relative (i.e. percentage) value! To get the average proportions of the audio stream, just check a few of your videos and calculate ...

Answer (score 1):

There are variables you don't mention, but you can make a quick estimate based on the video bit rate and the audio bit rate. With (say) 4800Kb/s video and 48Kb/s audio, the audio represents 1% of the file.